# SwiftUI: How to preview a view on a physical provisioned device?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

When using SwiftUI view previews, is there a way to get it displayed on my physical device?

```
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, simply activate "Preview on device" in the canvas view:

[image]